# Find array element by matching String with wildcard character

Tags: regex, unity-game-engine, string-matching

I want to have a if statement that goes through the whole array and is true when it finds elements with the name that starts with "Button" and after that it can be anything, something like:

```
if (Array[i].name == "Button*")
```

So for example it would be true when an element has the name "Button1" or "ButtonBlaBlaBla", but it would be false if the name doesn't start with "Button", for example "1Button".

PS: I am working in unity, but I am pretty sure this has nothing to do with it, so I posted here. If there is an existing post about the same problem, please link it to me.

Comment: Thanks for the help.

Comment: You're welcome. But by the way, this sort of name checking is not such a great idea in Unity. Try attaching a tag instead. If your buttons are tagged as "Button" (set tags in the inspector), checking `button.CompareTag("Button")` is very fast, and it's a little safer because you're not really allowed to mis-tag an object (tags are stored by the editor).

Comment: You can also check the component on the button: check if `button.GetComponent<SpecialButton>() != null`, or better yet, if you need information from that component, store it in a variable, then check if it's null. (Because in game development, you usually don't want to call functions twice if there's not a reason.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check whether `name.StartsWith("Button")` for to match `Button*`. `name.EndsWith("Button")` matches `*Button`. And to match `*Button*`, check `name.Contains("Button")`.

Answer (score 2):

You need to use `StartsWith()`

```
if(Array[i].name.StartsWith("Button"))
```

Answer (score 1):

There you have:

```
if(Array[i].name.StartsWith ("Button") )
```